# RXjs : How to create an operator on streams : scan operator where the accumulator state can be reset through an observable

Tags: rxjs

I need to create a new instance operator on streams with the following characteristics

- **Signature**

  `Rx.Observable.prototype.scan_with_reset(accumulator, seed$)`

  where :

  **Arguments**

  `accumulator (Function)`: An accumulator function to be invoked on each     element.

  `seed$ (Observable)` : An observable whose values will be used to restart the accumulator function. The accumulator function has the following signature `function accumulator_fn(accumulator_state, source_value)`. I want the value in `seed$` to reset `accumulator_state` to the `seed` value and emit the `seed` value.

  **Returns**
  *(Observable)* : An observable sequence which results from the comonadic bind operation (whatever that means, I am copying `Rxjs` documentation here). Vs. the normal `scan` operator, what happens here is that when the accumulator function is 'restarted' from the seed value emitted by the `seed$` observable, that seed value is emitted, and the next value to be emitted by the `scan_with_reset` operator will be `accumulator_fn(seed, source_value)`
- **Example of use :**

  `var seed$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
                           .map(function(ev){return ev.keyCode})
                           .startWith(0);
   var result$ = counter$.scan_with_reset(seed$, 
                            function accumulator_fn (acc, counter) {return acc+counter});`

  The following diagrams should explain more in details the expected results:

  `seed              : 0---------13--------27------------
  counter           : -1--5--2----6---2-----4---1---3---
  result            : 0-1--6--8-13-19--21-27-31--32--35-`

My initial attempt to do this was to modify the `accumulator_fn` to have the `seed$` modify a variable that would in the scope of `accumulator_fn` so I can detect changes in the function itself.

I pursue two goals here:

- have an implementation which is as stateless and closure-less as possible
- understand the mechanics behind defining one's own operators on
  streams, of which this would be hopefully a simple example

I had a look at `scan` source code : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/scan.js
but I am not sure where to go from there.

Does anybody has any experience in creating Rxjs stream operators? What are the conventions to follow and traps to avoid? Are there any examples of custom-made operators that I could look at? How would you go about implementing this particular one?

[UPDATE] : Some test code for the accepted answer

```
 var seed$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
                          .map(function(ev){return ev.keyCode})
                          .startWith(0);
 var counter$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                             .map(function(ev){return 1});
 var result$ = counter$.scanWithReset(seed$,
                                      function accumulator_fn (acc, counter) {return acc+counter});
 var s = function (x) {console.log("value: ", x)};
 var disposable = result$.subscribe(s)
```

Moving the mouse should show a value increase by 1, and pressing a key should restart the counter with the value of the key pressed.

Comment: This is a related question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69542888/2469567. I think the answer is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general case when creating operators it is generally easiest to use the `Observable.create` method which essentially defines how your `Observable` should behave when it is subscribed to or just wrap an existing set of operators ala [`share`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/share.js).

When you get more into performance there are some other considerations (`Observable.create` is not terribly efficient at scale) and you could look into creating a custom `Observable` like [map](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/map.js).

For your case I would recommend the former for right now. I would think of your problem really as several independent streams that we would like to flatten into a single stream. Each new stream will start when reset is triggered. This is really sounding an awful lot like `flatMap` to me:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.scanWithReset = function ($reset, accum, seed) {
    var source = this;
    //Creates a new Observable
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        //We will be reusing this source so we want to make sure it is shared
        var p = source.publish();


        var r = $reset
            //Make sure the seed is added first
            .startWith(seed)
            //This will switch to a new sequence with the associated value
            //every time $reset fires
            .flatMapLatest(function (resetValue) {
              //Perform the scan with the latest value
              return source.scan(accum, resetValue);
        });

        //Make sure every thing gets cleaned up
        return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
            r.subscribe(observer),
            //We are ready to start receiving from our source
            p.connect());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works wonders. I do understand the code but I would have had a hard time thinking to use `publish`, `connect` and `CompositeDisposable`, though now it all looks obvious. Modifying the `scan` source code seemed like the simplest way to include my logic through imperative coding and less inner knowledge of `Rxjs`. But yeah this way is more understandable.

Comment: just want to correct a small mistake/typo that I forgot to mention at that time and which came back to haunt me recently : instead of `source.scan(accum, resetValue)` it should be `p.scan(accum, resetValue)`

Comment: @paulpdaniels Can you please udpate it for RxJs 6+ ?