# RXJS Scan - withLatestFrom another observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to work out how to use scan to derive a new state whenever my input observable emits a new value, but I can't seem to get it working.

I want to output a new State every time the input$ observable emits a new value, but it should be derived from the current value of state$.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this? I have a feeling I've got the wrong idea altogether :-)

My code looks something like this:

```
const stateReducer = (state$: Observable<State>, input$: Observable<Input>) => {
  state$ = state$.pipe( startWith(DEFAULT_STATE) );

  const foo$: Observable<State> = input$.pipe(
    filter((input) => isFoo(input)),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    scan((acc, ([input, state]) => {
        //returns derived state
    });

   const bar$: Observable<State> = input$.pipe(
    filter((input) => isBar(input)),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    scan((acc, ([input, state]) => {
        //returns derived state
    });

   return merge(
     foo$,
     bar$
   );
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? `bar$` never emits or what? With `withLatestFrom` operator  `state$` needs to emit at least once.

Comment: + from the description its not clear why you need the `scan`. So just to be sure: to combine **latest** values from the streams -- you can simply use projection function, like `withLatestFrom(state$, (input, state)=> input + state)`.

Comment: I tried using withLatestFrom as my reducer function, but I never get the updated state on subsequent input values. It's always the default value.

Comment: I created a running codesandbox to demonstrate the issue. Any advice appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qk46vqxpw6?fontsize=14

Comment: @DanCarter You could use `scan` on your input$ -- to accumulate values on it `input$.scan(...).withLatestFrom...`. **OR** have a subject  for `currentState$` and write accumulations there, e.g. `input$.withLatestFrom(currentState$, (a,b)=>a+b).subscribe(currentState$)`. (Add guards for mem leaks). *Though atm its not clear how the `state$` updates should affect the reduced state*

Comment: @Kos state$ is an input to the calculate function and should be modified by the reducer functions, based on the input$ values.
The return value from the calculate function should be the new state$ (which in turn becomes the next value for the calculate function on subsequent input$ updates.

Comment: I think the problem may be something to do with how I am creating the source state$, but I can't pinpoint what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to use the result of an Observable as your seed value, `switchMap` will help.

[switchMap docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)

```
   const bar$: Observable<State> = state$.pipe(
    switchMap((state) => {
      return input$.pipe(
        filter((input) => isBar(input)),  
        scan((curState, input) => {
          // do some logic here
          return {...curState, prop: 'new value'}
        }, state);
      )
    })
```

I've made a sample CodePen for a more complete solution at https://codepen.io/askmattcairns/pen/LYjEoZz?editors=0010.

---

#### More Details

`switchMap` means to switch to the stream in here. So this code is saying, once `state$` emits a value, store it (as `state`), then wait for `input$` to emit.

When we call `scan`, its seed value (the second property of `scan`) is now the result of `state$`'s emitted value.

This will emit a new value any time `input$` receives a new value.

### Update to Code Sandbox

After digging in to your Code Sandbox, I better understand what the problem is. You can see my final output at https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-chaum-2b794?file=/src/index.tsx.

When you initialize your 2 inner streams `foo$` and `bar$`, they both reference `state$` using `withLatestFrom`. Each time `input$` emits, it still references the original value of `state`, using 0 as its starting total.